# How to calculate block memory size(MB,GB...) for each transaction block?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

Is there any API to calculate each block? How much size does it occupy?

Comment: You mean how much space an encoded block takes up? For what is that important? You could compress them afterwards.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi yes somewhat along those lines. Any docs you can point me to for reading about the same? I am curios to know about the entire process like block encoding which you mentioned..

Comment: On StackExchange questions have to be asked with a very narrow scope, otherwise they cannot be answered with one simple post. You can ask in the Matrix chat for more general questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the block and then print the encoded size with PolkadotJS like such:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

// Load the last block
const lastBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock();
console.log(`Block ${lastBlock.block.header.number} with ${lastBlock.block.extrinsics.length} \
extrinsics has ${lastBlock.encodedLength} bytes`);
```

Prints something like `Block 14878286 with 2 extrinsics has 32567 bytes`.
Should be easy to extend for subscribing to new blocks.